# Populate NSOutlineView with data - Swift

Tags: cocoa, swift, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I am trying to create a sidebar in my OS X application.

I have an NSOutlineView in my xib file.

I also have a a Swift file that looks like this:

```
import Cocoa

class TKSidebarDataSource: NSObject, NSOutlineViewDataSource {

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView,
        child index: Int,
        ofItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject {
            return "Item"
    }

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView,
        isItemExpandable item: AnyObject) -> Bool {
            return true;
    }

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView,
        numberOfChildrenOfItem item: AnyObject?) -> Int {
            return 4
    }


}
```

I want to connect my swift file to my NSOutlineView in order to populate the view with my data. How do you do this?  I have looked around at a lot of different places but nothing seems to be working.

---

Update:

A lot of solutions suggest I ctrl-click and drag from the datasource connection of the NSOutlineView to the *File's Owner* placeholder.  The only problem with that solution is that the datasource isn't the *File's owner*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in -windowDidLoad (or -loadView if in a view controller), set the table's data source:

```
[outlineView setDataSource:aTKSideBarDataSource];
```

or

```
outlineView.setDataSource(aTKSideBarDataSource)
```